# Excel - Count the number of matches for two values at the same time

Tags: excel

I have the following tables :

- Table 1 :

  `01/01/2020 PERSON1
  01/01/2020 PERSON3
  01/01/2020 PERSON1
  05/01/2020 PERSON2`
- Table 2 :

`PEOPLE/DATE 01/01/2020 02/01/2020 03/01/2020 04/01/2020
PERSON1
PERSON2
PERSON3`

For each person in table 2 I want to count the number of time they are present at the specified date.
For example : if Table1!DATE = 01/01/2020 AND if Table1!PERSON = PERSON1 -> result 2 in table 2.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Sounds like you want `CountIfs()` to account for multiple criteria.

Comment: Assuming Table1 is in column A and B, and Table 2 in D and you need to enter formula from E2 to end of Table 2.. Enter this formula and copy .. `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,E$1,$B:$B,$D2)`

Comment: @NareshBhople Your formula worked! Thank you.